# Prob and statistics question

Tags: probability

An urn contains $4$ balls numbered 1 2 3 4 respectively.
Two balls are drawn without replacement let $A$ be the event that sum is $5$. 
Let $B$ be the event that first ball is 1.
Compute $\mathbb{P}(A/B)$ AND $\mathbb{P}(B/A)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like routine homework problems and which show no effort.  What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?  People will meet you half way if you show some effort.

Comment: [Edit] your post to include those details. Also see the [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial.

Comment: As far as i know event A should be either (4,1) or (3,2) .   Event B is (1)              i know how to Compute P(A/B) AND P(B/A) but i'm not sure about the events.

Answer (score 1):

Recognize that since we are drawing without replacement, our sample space can be described as the ways in which we can draw two balls in sequence without replacement and that these ways are equiprobable.  The ways explicitly are $\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)\}$ and there are $4\times 3 = 12$ elements in this sample space (*seen more quickly by applying multiplication principle/rule of product rather than by counting by hand*).

Now... event A, the event that we got a sum of five includes $(4,1)$ and $(3,2)$ but also includes $(2,3)$ and $(1,4)$.  We find that $Pr(A)=\frac{4}{12}=\frac{1}{3}$.  This can also be seen more directly by noting that whichever first ball we picked, there is always exactly one ball remaining that will make the sum a five.

We also find that $B$ includes the outcomes $(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)$ and so $Pr(B)=\frac{3}{12}=\frac{1}{4}$ which could have been seen more directly by noting that there are four equally likely balls that could have been drawn first, only one of them being the ball #1.

Next, we find that the event where the first ball is a $1$ and the sum is a $5$, i.e. the event $A\cap B$, contains exactly one outcome... $(1,4)$.  This implies then that $Pr(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{12}$

Now, we have all of the pieces we might want to finish the problem.  Recall that $Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$ and that $Pr(B\mid A)=\frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(A)}$ and plug in the values we found.

> $Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{1/12}{3/12}=\frac{1}{3}$ and $Pr(B\mid A)=\frac{1/12}{4/12}=\frac{1}{4}$

With practice, you can spot what the conditional probabilities will be equal to without needing to resort to using the direct definition and you could probably have spotted these answers without any effort.

Comment: Thank you so much .

Comment: What if the balls are drawn with replacement?

Comment: @nart then the sample space would also include $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)$ in addition to all of the others mentioned previously.  Do you see how that affects the calculations?

Comment: Yes i think the sample space will be 16 in total , and we will get different results.